# Evolution operator of a $N$-particle system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, many-body, time-evolution

Consider a $N$-particle system with a nearest-neighbour interaction of the form
$$H = - \hbar g(t) \sum_i A_i B_{i+1}$$
where $A_i, B_i$ are an operators acting on the $i$-th particle with $[A_i, B_j] = 0\; \forall i,j $. Assume that the eigenvalue-decomposition of $A$ and $B$ is known.
I'm now interested in the time evolution of the full-system state, thus I need to evaluate the time evolution operator
$$U = \text{exp}(-i \pi \sum_i A_i B_{i+1} ).$$
Note: I took for simplicity a time $t$ where $\int_0^t dt g(t) = \pi$.

In the end, I would like to express this operator in its eigenbasis, i.e. $$U = \sum_j e^{-i \pi \lambda_j} | \phi_j \rangle \langle \phi_j |$$

I figured that, since all $A$ and $B$ commute, it might be useful to write $U$ as a product with the help of the BCH formula
$$ U = e^{-i \pi} \prod_i \text{exp}(A_i B_{i+1} )$$
but unfortunately I struggle with writing down the eigenbasis of $U$ to perform this calculation.

Comment: $U$ is in general non-Hermitian (it's only required to be unitary). That means its eigenvectors do not necessarily form a basis. Did you mean perhaps to decompose $U$ with the energy eigenstates?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. $U$ and $H$ always have an identical set of eigenvectors, no?

Comment: No, that's not true. $U$ transforms the eigenvectors of $H$ into the eigenvectors of $UHU^{-1}\neq H$, so that  these states are not eigenvectors of $U$.

Comment: But let $|E\rangle$ be an energy eigenstate, i.e. $H |E\rangle = E |E\rangle$ while $U = \text{exp}(a H)$. Then it holds that $U |E\rangle = \sum_n 1/n! (aH)^n |E\rangle = \sum_n 1/n! a^n E^n |E\rangle = e^{aE} |E\rangle$ .

Comment: Oh, nevermind then, my mistake. I was ignoring the fact that $U$ was the time evolution operator in this case.